Body/shell of bottom bracket cartridge stuck inside shell after removal of cups & spindle? Or is this something else?
I was removing an FSA(from inscription on seal) square taper BB from an old bike which required a lot of effort (clamping the tool was required, 1m lever and anti-rust not enough alone). Spindle, loose bearings and metal pieces came out with the NDS, and a cup on the other side was removed afterwards. Nothing resembling a cartridge body came out and it seems to be left inside. The question is, can this be anything else?
An old shimano BB indicates that the diameter of this steel thing is indeed the same as a new 68mm shell cartridge unit, but this stuck body(?) seems like an extremely tight fit except from the outermost parts on both sides(red arrows) where there is some room between the cylinder and the frame itself where I have poked out some debris. What is left seems like solid metal.
Can this be something else than the body of a cartridge unit? If not, any advice on how to remove it? I tried rust-remover and pounding it via an old BB with a matching body diameter with no sucess and I don't want to destroy the edges preventing it to be pushed or hammered out.


It was indeed the body(cylinder) of the BB cartridge unit.
Anti-rust spray and keeping hammering on it via an old bottom bracket cartridge unit eventually pushed it out. It's important to make sure you hit pretty precicely since edge on edge is a small target. It was very poor conditions underneath. I'll leave the post for the future in case someone needs help and encouragement in a smiliar bizzare situation.

Great work!   One handy tool is to have  "junk" sockets to use as drivers.  Find one exactly the right size and carefully tap it through.

Please don't delete. Mark as an answer

Was it stuck because the cable guide securing bolt was too long, would you say? That is quite common. The solution would be to unwind it a couple of turns, allowing the bb part to fall out.

@Noise No, that was not the problem. I removed it prior to BB removal to get in some anti-rust & lubrication (no additional drainage hole in the shell). Inspection afterwards also showed it would have not caused a problem for my bike, but it is a potential issue to avoid. It was just 7ish winters of salty slush and corrosion.

The cylinder had bonded/corroded to the frame, making it incredibly hard to get out the cups on each side because the BB had to be pulled apart in the process (bond to frame was stronger than the bond between the BB-parts). It all made sense in retrospect.
